# ¿Que motivo debo usar al reportar una pregunta en la que se pide que le hagan la tarea?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

He estado reportando las preguntas que únicamente muestran un enunciado, cuando se me abre la ventanita donde tengo que poner el motivo de mi reporte, siempre marco el de "Necesita detalles o aclaraciones". Sin embargo, no sé si esto sea correcto o todo este tiempo he estado reportando preguntas sin sentido alguno.

¿Cuál opción debo marcar?

Comment: Me parece que esto podría dar paso a solicitar que se incluya explícitamente el motivo: **Solicita que le hagan sus deberes escolares**

Comment: También creo que _Necesita detalles o aclaraciones_ es la opción más adecuada de entre las que hay actualmente. Al fin y al cabo, se necesita que el AP explique qué ha intentado. Además, para dar guía a los usuarios se podría traducir esto de Meta SO: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/1983854).

Comment: Tu opinión siempre es muy acertada @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' seguiré el consejo